# Is there a way to get what is clicked in any windows?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I managed to get the position (x,y) of mousse clicked event in windows with C# and Win32 API from the code at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx (using Version 1 because I have a problem with version 2)
But I want to know what is clicked not the position on the screen.
For example, click the "Bold Button" in MS Word.
Is there a way to archive this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch a window handle from [WindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [ChildWindowFromPointEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632677%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), then query the window handle with [GetWindowInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633516%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) etc. I don't think there's a trivial way to identify a button from Word, though.

Comment: Is the way you suggest will work for any application I can see on screen?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [AutomationElement.FromPoint()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.frompoint.aspx) that's part of UI Automation - this suite of APIs is often used by automated test and accessibility apps that want to get information about the UI of other processes. For apps that support it (most of the UI in Windows and most MS apps), you can get information about the UI element, not just the outer window. This sample app prints out the name and type (eg 'button') of the item under the cursor.

It's not supported everywhere, may not work in many non-MS apps (though is supported by Firefox); but will at least get you better results than  WindowFromPoint etc.

```
// Compile using: csc ItemAtPoint.cs /r:UIAutomationClient.dll /r:WindowsBase.dll

using System;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class ItemAtPoint
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Place pointer over item and hit return...");
        Console.ReadLine();

        // Get the AutomationElement that represents the window handle...
        System.Windows.Point point = new System.Windows.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
        AutomationElement el = AutomationElement.FromPoint(point);

        // Print out the type of the item and its name
        Console.WriteLine("item is a \"{0}\" with name \"{1}\"", el.Current.LocalizedControlType, el.Current.Name);
    }
}
```